# Proof for finding if there exists a pair $A[i]$ and $A[j]$ in sorted array where $A[j] - A[i] = d$

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, solution-verification

I am new to writing out proofs and was asked to come up with a algorithm for the following that can run in $O(n)$ time.

Let $A$ be a sorted array of $n$ integers. Given a value $d$, we want to know if there are two indices $i, j$ such that $A[j] − A[i] = d$.

My algorithm implementation so far :
Algorithm Steps:

1. Initialize $i$ and $j$ (two indices) to $0, 1$ respectively
2. Run loop to to calculate $\text{arr}[j] - \text{arr}[i] = d$

- If $\text{arr}[j] - \text{arr}[i] > d$, then increment $i$
- If $\text{arr}[j] - \text{arr}[i] <d$, then increment $j$
- If $\text{arr}[j] - \text{arr}[i]=d$, then you found a pair

I know this works and runs in $O(n)$. Where I'm having trouble is writing a proof for this. In this type scenario, how would you write an induction proof or can it be a case analysis? Any help would be great!

Comment: HINT: Each time through the loop you increment exactly one of the indices by $1$. What’s the maximum possible number of increments before you’ve either found a suitable pair of indices or demonstrated that there isn’t one?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Since you increment exactly one of the indices  (i and j) by 1, we exit the loop if either i or j become n. So would the maximum number of increments be just the number (n-(j+1))+ (n-(i+1)) + 1 if they are initialized to i=0, and j = 1?

Comment: You probably don’t want to exit right away when $j=n$: it’s possible that if you increment $i$ one or more times, you’ll still find a pair $\langle i,n\rangle$ such that $A[n]-A[i]=d$. But you don’t have to be too precise here to get the desired result: you certainly know that at the very worst you’ll increment $i$ $n$ times and $j$ $n-1$ times. In particular, then, the total number of increments is guaranteed to be less than $2n$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott! I was assuming j would exit at n as it would be out of bounds since the last index of the array would be (n-1). But this makes total sense. Now for a formal proof, is the explanation regarding how we increment and maximum total number of increments sufficient for a proof?

Comment: Ah, okay: if the last index of $A$ is $n-1$, then you’re right about exiting at $j=n$. And yes, that argument should suffice, provided that you can assume that initial and final overhead is constant and therefore ignorable and that the rest of the processing time is more or less proportional to the number of times the loop is executed.